# Is $\forall x [\exists y\ Q(x,y)\ \lor\ \forall z\ \neg Q(x,z)]$ valid?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is $\forall x [\exists y\ Q(x,y)\ \lor\ \forall z\ \neg Q(x,z)]$ valid or merely a satisfiable formula?

I would appreciate an explanation as to why, because it seems a bit counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: You are probably asking whether the above sentence is **valid** or not. In usual terminology, we use **tautology** as an alternative to refer to valid formulae *of the propositional calculus*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\forall x:[\exists y: Q(x,y) \lor \forall z:\neg Q(x,z)]$$

Apply the laws of distribution over quantification; in this case: the universal of a negation is the negation of an existential.

$$\forall x:[\exists y:Q(x,y) \lor \neg\exists z:Q(x,z)]$$

If this isn't clear, we can change the symbols used in each scope as long as the new symbol isn't already used in the same scope.

$$\forall x:[\exists y:Q(x,y) \lor \neg\exists y:Q(x,y)]$$

So: Is this a tautology?

Comment: Does it matter if we assume the law of the excluded middle?  For example, $Q$ could be "program $x$ halts on input $y$", which is generally undecidable.  I haven't really thought it out though.

Comment: @DanielV The atomic formulae in predicate logic must be Boolean functions; outputting a fixed True or False for any given input.  The middle is excluded.  There is no indecision.

Comment: @BBentzen The universal quantified predicate is equivalent to a conjunction of the predicate for all entities in the universe: $[\forall x:P(x)] \equiv [\bigwedge_{x\in\mathcal U} P(x)]$, and likewise the existential is equivalent to the disjunction across the universe: $[\exists x:P(x)] \equiv [\bigvee_{x\in\mathcal U} P(x)]$.  So we apply DeMorgan's laws to obtain: $[\neg\forall x\, P(x)]\iff [\neg\bigwedge_{x\in\mathcal U} P(x)]\iff [\bigvee_{x\in\mathcal U} \neg P(x)]\iff [\exists x\,\neg P(x)]$ and *vice versa*.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the late reply. The counter-intuitiveness for me was the fact that one can replace $z$ with $y$ and it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that exists $x$ such that for all $y$, $\neg Q(x;y)$ and there exists $z$ such that $Q(x;z)$. Then, for this $z$ we have $\neg Q(x;z)$ and $Q(x;z)$ simultaneously. This is a contradiction.

Comment: That $\lor$ is: 'or' not 'and'.

Comment: Yes, and the negation of '$A$ or $B$' is '$\neg A$ and $\neg B$'.

Comment: Why are you negating the disjunction?